# what are the numbers in the operation names when profiling an application

Tags: profiling, profiler, jax

What are the numbers in "fusion_2", "fusion_4"? Where do they come from? Thank you!

[image: JAX profiling]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers exist to de-duplicate the names of generated HLO operations. The first fusion operation created by the compiler is called `fusion`, the next is `fusion_2`, then `fusion_3`, and so on.

Note that the order of creation does not necessarily match the order of execution.

Comment: But why fusion_3 appeared before fusion_2 as you can see in the picture.

Comment: `fusion_2` is created before `fusion_3`, but executed after.

Comment: I see. So, these op names were generated during compiling time which is separated from the execution process. Thank you Jake!